# Material-UI: customizing Box component with withStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use to customizing MUI components with withStyles shortcut, but when I do this with the Box it gives me "classes=[object Object]" property in the DOM. However component works as expected with customization applied.

```
const SplitBoxStyle = {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: '#eaeaea',
    width: 1,
    height: 24,
    marginRight: 5
  }
}
const SplitBox = withStyles(SplitBoxStyle)(Box)

export const () => {
  return <Box>Here is styled box: <SplitBox /></Box>
}
```

it gives HTML:

```
<div class="MuiBox-root MuiBox-root-122 Styled(MuiBox)-root-87" classes="[object Object]" style="margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 15px;"></div>
```

So is this way wrong? Or how to remove these annoying classes property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little modified code.

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

const SplitBoxStyle = {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "#eaeaea",
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    marginRight: 5
  }
};

function SplitBox(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return <Box className={classes.root}>Here is styled box</Box>;
}

export default withStyles(SplitBoxStyle)(SplitBox);
```

Here is the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7p1we?file=/demo.js).

Comment: Thanks, I've ended with this:


const SplitBox = withStyles(SplitBoxStyle)(({
  classes,
  children,
  ...props
}) => <Box className={classes.root} {...props}>{children}</Box>)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue however this solution doesn't work with Typescript. The compiler emits a warning about the `classes` prop. Any idea how to fix it in this case?

Comment: Just found a way and added an alternative answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

When using TypeScript, a custom interface has to be declared to allow using the `classes` property. This way:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyledComponentProps, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Box, BoxProps } from "@material-ui/core";

interface Props extends BoxProps, StyledComponentProps {}

function SplitBox({ classes, children, ...props }: Props) {
  return <Box className={classes?.root} {...props}>{children}</Box>;
}

export default withStyles(SplitBoxStyle)({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "#eaeaea",
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    marginRight: 5
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working TS version for MUIv5:

```
import { Box, BoxProps } from '@mui/material';
import withStyles, { StyledComponentProps } from '@mui/styles/withStyles';

function BoxBase({ classes, ...props }: BoxProps & StyledComponentProps) {
  return <Box className={classes?.root} {...props} />;
}

export const MyBox = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 0,
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
  },
}))(BoxBase);
```